# Exclude import w/ Babel?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

My application is React JSX/ES6 using Webpack+Babel for compilation. My test suite is Tape + Shallow Render and up to now I've been able to run everything through `babel-node` (and `babel-istanbul`) without running Webpack and a browser or headless browser.

Then I needed an asset. A `.mp3`, to be specific.

What I have is basically:

```
import ding from '/sounds/ding.mp3';
...
<audio src={ding} autoPlay={true} />
```

This works in both development and production, but without Webpack (and `file-loader`) it gets tripped up:

```
/Users/orbiteleven/project/client/sounds/ding.mp3:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ID3
                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Is there a way to exclude imports via Babel (or some other method)? `ignore` doesn't do the trick, as it just prevents Babel from parsing the file, but includes it regardless.

I'd love to not have to include the complexity (and slowness) of something like Karma + PhantomJS/Chrome/Electron/Whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Change the import to a format like `import ding from '../sounds/ding';`. Set up a module named `ding.js` there (noop module basically) and use a `resolve.alias` on webpack's side to map the import to the mp3 file. You'll end up with

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '../sounds/ding': PATHS.ding
  }
}
```